# PostgreSQL permissions explained

Tags: postgresql

Please explain the output of the `\z` command in PostgreSQL. I understand the permission, I read the documentation, but somehow I missed the interpretation of the output of `\z`.

```
datastore_default=> \z

                                    Access privileges
 Schema |      Name       | Type  |         Access privileges         | Column access privileges 
--------+-----------------+-------+-----------------------------------+--------------------------
 public | _table_metadata | view  | ckan_default=arwdDxt/ckan_default+| 
        |                 |       | datastore_default=r/ckan_default +| 
        |                 |       | readonlyuser=r/ckan_default      +| 
 public | foo             | table | ckan_default=arwdDxt/ckan_default+| 
        |                 |       | datastore_default=r/ckan_default +| 
        |                 |       | readonlyuser=r/ckan_default      +|
```

Somehow `readonlyuser` seems to be able to read tables `foo` and _foo but in practice it cannot. Both commands return an error:

```
sudo -u postgres psql -d datastore_default -U readonlyuser -c 'SELECT * FROM foo'
sudo -u postgres psql -d datastore_default -U readonlyuser -c 'SELECT * FROM public.foo'
ERROR:  permission denied for schema public
LINE 1: SELECT * FROM public.foo
```

Edit: apparently I had a poor understanding of how database and schema permissions work. First of all only the db admin (user postgres) or the owner of the database (in my case user ckan_default) can grant other users privileges on a specific database. The schema is only at a database level, so it's ok that I added `readonlyuser` the permission to see the public schema, it cannot select from other databases anyway.

Comment: I have added some details on reading the ACL to my answer.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

The error says permission denied for **schema public** (emphasis mine)

You need to give readonlyuser rights on schema public:

```
GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA public TO readonlyuser;
```

The contents of the ACL is explained on [this page](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/interactive/sql-grant.html). The most relevant part quoted here:

> ```
> rolename=xxxx -- privileges granted to a role
>         =xxxx -- privileges granted to PUBLIC
>
>             r -- SELECT ("read")
>             w -- UPDATE ("write")
>             a -- INSERT ("append")
>             d -- DELETE
>             D -- TRUNCATE
>             x -- REFERENCES
>             t -- TRIGGER
>             X -- EXECUTE
>             U -- USAGE
>             C -- CREATE
>             c -- CONNECT
>             T -- TEMPORARY
>       arwdDxt -- ALL PRIVILEGES (for tables, varies for other objects)
>             * -- grant option for preceding privilege
>
>         /yyyy -- role that granted this privilege
> ```

The + are part of the way psql formats the result, they are not part of the value.

Comment: Thank you, but it still does not seem to work.
`sudo -u postgres psql -d datastore_default -U ckan_default -c 'GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA public TO readonlyuser;'
WARNING:  no privileges were granted for "public"
GRANT`. \z prints the same thing. I have PostgreSQL 9.1.14 (Ubuntu 12.04 LTS)

Comment: I think it gives that message when the user with which you are logged in does not have sufficient rights to grant those rights. You should have GRANT privileges or are the owner of public or be superuser.

Comment: thank you. it is clear now. I had the impression that the + has some special meaning.

Comment: I have a postgres user who is the owner of a table which it can't truncate... I see in the ACL for that user it is: `arwdRxt`. What does it mean and how is it different from `arwdDxt`? My assumption is that it is because of `D` vs. `R` where `D` stands for `TRUNCATE`.

Comment: What version of postgresql are you using? AFAIK capitol R is not valid.

Comment: just to add to @Eelke 's comment, the `GRANT USAGE` is a different permission, so the user must have that permission as well to be able to `GRANT USAGE`

Comment: The [psql_access_priv_decoder](https://github.com/tpo/little_shell_scripts#psql_access_priv_decoder) is a tool that you can feed the output of `psql` and that will explain you the access privileges in clear text.